# How does heart rate change when entering N1 sleep?

Tags: cardiology, sleep

I would like to know how the heart rate changes as a person enters N1 (NREM 1) sleep from a wakeful state. The focus is on entering N1, and it would be great to have time-series data to see the pattern of the decrease, but a  textual description of the decrease would be good too. Most importantly, by how much does heart rate decrease from resting to N1, and how quickly does it fall?